# Edit review: edit that appends alternate solution to an answer

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I'm looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19256995) edit.

I've gone over the editing [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) and a number of conversations here on meta, but I haven't found anything that I can confidently apply to this situation.

I don't know whether this counts as a change to the author's intent. It's not an update to an obsolete answer, and it didn't come from the comments. It doesn't seem to hurt the answer, as far as I can tell.

I'm not sure what to do with it. Thoughts?

Comment: I would reject with *attempt to reply*.

Comment: About the request: It's rejected now. If there are multiple approaches to solve a problem (and the accepted solution is not outdated/wrong), then the new approach should be posted as a separate answer. Otherwise it is impossible to vote on each of them separately.

Comment: @BDL Thanks for the theoretical underpinning.  That helps a lot. Cheers.

Comment: Such an edit is fine if it enhances the answer.  But most people that review don't know enough about the [tag] subject to judge the technical accuracy and reject such an edit.  Ideally they would know, but that's not something that is easy to achieve.